# Применимы ли правила написания единиц измерения к выдуманным обозначениям в играх?

Tags: сокращения

Извините, если этот вопрос не совсем к вам, просто не знаю куда ещё обратиться.

Наткнулся на статью, но не могу понять, применимы ли правила написания единиц измерения к онлайн играм или мемам?

В играх тысячи обозначают буквой "к", 1000 = 1к, 2900 = 2,9к и т. п. И всё бы ничего, но мнение людей разнится по этому поводу, верно ли такое написание в играх или же нет. Распространяются ли правила на те же игровые форумы или сами игры.

Пожалуйста, проясните ситуацию, верно ли применять правила к выдуманным обозначениям и мемам, как написанное ниже, или же это просто мнение отдельного человека?

> Написание года через К ошибочное сразу с нескольких точек зрения. В Международной системе (СИ) приставку "к" используют для сокращения количества нулей при записи в основных единицах измерения: метр (длина), килограмм (масса), секунда (время), ампер (электрический ток), кельвин (температура), моль (количество вещества) и кандела (сила света).
>
> Например, пишут 5К вместо 5000. Но с научной точки зрения этот принцип не используется для обычных чисел, а только для единиц измерения.
>
> Кроме того, приставка К применима только к идущему впереди значению, то есть 2К17 это 200017. Отсутствие знака между между знаком и числом в математике означает умножение, тогда 2К*17=2000*17=34000.
>
> В маркировке сопротивления резисторов 8K2 обозначает 8,2 килоома, то есть К стоит на месте запятой в десятичной дроби. В таком случае 2К17 это 2,17 килоома или 2170 ома. Правильным написанием 2017 через К будет 2,017К.

https://memepedia.ru/2k17/ - ссылка на статью.

Извиняюсь, что так сумбурно, надеюсь, вы меня поймёте. Спасибо за внимание, с нетерпением жду ответа. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Насколько я помню, обозначение **"2k"** в качестве заменителя **"2000"** появилось еще в середине 90-х по мере приближения пресловутой **"Проблемы-2000"**. Тогда это было действительно сокращение, т.к. два символа **"2k"** заменяли четыре символа **"2000"**.
Но наступил и успешно закончился двухтысячный год, а система обозначений **"2k"** настолько прочно вошла в лексикон ИТ-шников того времени, что следующий год стали называть **"2k01"** (или даже просто **"2k1"**), т.е. первый год после **"2k"**. За ним шел **"2k02"** и т.д.
Тезис о том, что отсутствие знака всегда означает умножение, просто несостоятелен, т.к. отсутствие знака обозначает умножение только тогда, когда буква расположена ПОСЛЕ цифры. Если же буква расположена ДО цифры, такое обозначение означает конкатенацию, т.е. **"2k17"** - это не **"2k * 17"**, а **"2 * k + 17"**, т.е. **"2017"**, т.к. **"k"** обозначает **"kilo"** - [тысячу](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE-).
Что касается маркировки резисторов, упомянутой в статье, то это настолько узкая область применения, что экстраполировать ее на всю систему буквенно-цифровых сокращений чисел - просто несерьезно.

Answer (score 0):

> Применимы ли правила написания единиц измерения к выдуманным
>   обозначениям в играх?

Ваня, а выдумщики обозначений с чем-то там совпадающим считаться не обязаны. А на плагиат не тянет.